# Django for loop to display all objects in database

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, sqlite

```
def homepage(response):
    data = Project_types.objects.all()
    return render(response, 'main/homepage.html',{'projects':data})


def hacks(response):
    return render(response, 'main/hacks.html', {})

def games(response):
    return render(response, 'main/games.html', {})
```

All I need to know is how to iterate through each object in the variable "data" in html. I want it displayed in the most simple way possible !

Answer (score 5):

Using the **FOR** template tags you can iterate through the objects in the data list ...

**templatename.html:**

```
{% for iteratorname in projects %}
    <h1> {{ iteratorname.attributes }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

[Please read the documentation for more details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: @Selcuk ... Thanks.. did not see that !

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for** template tag:

```html
{% for project in projects %}
    <p> {{project.attributes}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```